# Jquery plugin 'Sliding Panel Photowall Gallery' is not showing my images as JPEG

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, plugins

I am using this jquery plugin ([enter link description here](http://tympanus.net/Tutorials/SlidingPanelPhotowallGallery/)) which I really love, and the demo site works perfectly. However, when I replace the images with my images and don't touch any of the code (I want to test it before I customize it), I get an error and the images don't load.

The gallery works like this: You click on a thumbnail and the script calls the corresponding full-size image based on what you put in the "Alt" tag for that thumbnail. The problem is that when I added my images, I get this error: **Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)**

Upon further inspection I found the problem, but have no idea how to fix it. The "GET" method is looking for a 'text/html' file instead of a JPEG. I am confused because I can't figure out why it doesn't see my image paths as jpg when it does with the original demo site.

Here is my site: http://secondstoryinteriors.com/lookbook/

I have also supplied the code for the entire page. Thanks for your help!

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Sliding Panel Photowall Gallery with jQuery</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
    <meta name="description" content="Sliding Panel Photowall Gallery with jQuery" />
    <meta name="keywords" content="jquery, images, gallery, photowall, slideshow"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" type="text/css" media="screen"/>
</head>
<style>
    a{
        color:#262626;
        text-decoration:none;
    }
    a:hover{
        text-decoration:underline;
    }
    span.reference{
        position:fixed;
        left:30px;
        bottom:0px;
        font-size:9px;
    }
    span.reference a{
        color:#aaa;
    }
    span.reference a:hover{
        color:#262626;
        text-decoration:none;
    }

</style>
<body>
    <div class="infobar">
        <span id="description"></span>
        <span id="loading">Loading Image</span>
        <span class="reference">
            <h2>FALL/WINTER 2013 LOOKBOOK</a>
        </span>
    </div>
    <div id="thumbsWrapper">
        <div id="content" >
            <img src="thumbs/1.jpg" alt="images/1.jpg" title="Beatriz_Florido_01 © studio.es"/>
            <img src="thumbs/2.jpg" alt="images/2.jpg" title="Nuria_09 © studio.es by Vincent Boiteau"/>
            <img src="thumbs/3.jpg" alt="images/3.jpg" title="Nuria_08 © studio.es by Vincent Boiteau"/>
            <img src="thumbs/4.jpg" alt="images/4.jpg" title="Nuria_07 © studio.es by Vincent Boiteau"/>
            <img src="thumbs/5.jpg" alt="images/5.jpg" title="Nuria_06 © studio.es by Vincent Boiteau"/>
            <img src="thumbs/6.jpg" alt="images/6.jpg" title="Nuria_05 © studio.es by Vincent Boiteau"/>
            <img src="thumbs/7.jpg" alt="images/7.jpg" title="Nuria_04 © studio.es by Vincent Boiteau"/>
            <img src="thumbs/8.jpg" alt="images/8.jpg" title="Nuria_03 © studio.es by Vincent Boiteau"/>
            <img src="thumbs/9.jpg" alt="images/9.jpg" title="Nuria_02 © studio.es by Vincent Boiteau"/>
            <img src="thumbs/10.jpg" alt="images/10.jpg" title="Nuria_01 © studio.es by Vincent Boiteau"/>
            <img src="thumbs/11.jpg" alt="images/11.jpg" title="Janne_Nielsen_07 © studio.es by Vincent Boiteau"/>
            <img src="thumbs/12.jpg" alt="images/12.jpg" title="Janne_Nielsen_03 © studio.es by Vincent Boiteau"/>
            <img src="thumbs/13.jpg" alt="images/13.jpg" title="Janne_Nielsen_06 © studio.es by Vincent Boiteau"/>
            <img src="thumbs/14.jpg" alt="images/14.jpg" title="Janne_Nielsen_05 © studio.es by Vincent Boiteau"/>
            <img src="thumbs/15.jpg" alt="images/15.jpg" title="Janne_Nielsen_04 © studio.es by Vincent Boiteau"/>
            <img src="thumbs/16.jpg" alt="images/16.jpg" title="Janne_Nielsen_01 © studio.es by Vincent Boiteau"/>
            <img src="thumbs/17.jpg" alt="images/17.jpg" title="Beatriz_Ruiz_10 © studio.es by Vincent Boiteau"/>
            <img src="thumbs/18.jpg" alt="images/18.jpg" title="Beatriz_Ruiz_08 © studio.es by Vincent Boiteau"/>
            <img src="thumbs/19.jpg" alt="images/19.jpg" title="Beatriz_Ruiz_06 © studio.es by Vincent Boiteau"/>
            <img src="thumbs/20.jpg" alt="images/20.jpg" title="Beatriz_Ruiz_05 © studio.es by Vincent Boiteau"/>
            <img src="thumbs/21.jpg" alt="images/21.jpg" title="Beatriz_Ruiz_04 © studio.es by Vincent Boiteau"/>
            <img src="thumbs/22.jpg" alt="images/22.jpg" title="Beatriz_Ruiz_02 © studio.es by Vincent Boiteau"/>
            <img src="thumbs/23.jpg" alt="images/23.jpg" title="Beatriz_Ruiz_01 © studio.es by Vincent Boiteau"/>
            <img src="thumbs/24.jpg" alt="images/24.jpg" title="Fashion 9  © studio.es by Vincent Boiteau"/>

            <div class="placeholder"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="panel">
        <div id="wrapper">
            <a id="prev"></a>
            <a id="next"></a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- The JavaScript -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function() {
            /* this is the index of the last clicked picture */
            var current = -1;
            /* number of pictures */
            var totalpictures = $('#content img').size();
            /* speed to animate the panel and the thumbs wrapper */
            var speed   = 500;

            /* show the content */
            $('#content').show();

            /*
            when the user resizes the browser window,
            the size of the picture being viewed is recalculated;
             */
            $(window).bind('resize', function() {
                var $picture = $('#wrapper').find('img');
                resize($picture);
            });

            /*
            when hovering a thumb, animate it's opacity
            for a cool effect;
            when clicking on it, we load the corresponding large image;
            the source of the large image is stored as 
            the "alt" attribute of the thumb image
             */
            $('#content > img').hover(function () {
                var $this   = $(this);
                $this.stop().animate({'opacity':'1.0'},200);
            },function () {
                var $this   = $(this);
                $this.stop().animate({'opacity':'0.4'},200);
            }).bind('click',function(){
                var $this   = $(this);

                /* shows the loading icon */
                $('#loading').show();

                $('<img/>').load(function(){
                    $('#loading').hide();

                    if($('#wrapper').find('img').length) return;
                    current     = $this.index();
                    var $theImage   = $(this);
                    /*
                    After it's loaded we hide the loading icon
                    and resize the image, given the window size;
                    then we append the image to the wrapper
                    */

                    resize($theImage);

                    $('#wrapper').append($theImage);
                    /* make its opacity animate */
                    $theImage.fadeIn(800);

                    /* and finally slide up the panel */
                    $('#panel').animate({'height':'100%'},speed,function(){
                        /*
                        if the picture has a description,
                        it's stored in the title attribute of the thumb;
                        show it if it's not empty
                         */
                        var title = $this.attr('title');
                        if(title != '') 
                            $('#description').html(title).show();
                        else 
                            $('#description').empty().hide();

                        /*
                        if our picture is the first one,
                        don't show the "previous button"
                        for the slideshow navigation;
                        if our picture is the last one,
                        don't show the "next button"
                        for the slideshow navigation
                         */
                        if(current==0)
                            $('#prev').hide();
                        else
                            $('#prev').fadeIn();
                        if(current==parseInt(totalpictures-1))
                            $('#next').hide();
                        else
                            $('#next').fadeIn();
                        /*
                        we set the z-index and height of the thumbs wrapper 
                        to 0, because we want to slide it up afterwards,
                        when the user clicks the large image
                         */
                        $('#thumbsWrapper').css({'z-index':'0','height':'0px'});
                    });
                }).attr('src', $this.attr('alt'));
            });

            /*
            when hovering a large image,
            we want to slide up the thumbs wrapper again,
            and reset the panel (like it was initially);
            this includes removing the large image element
             */
            $('#wrapper > img').live('click',function(){
                $this = $(this);
                $('#description').empty().hide();

                $('#thumbsWrapper').css('z-index','10')
                .stop()
                .animate({'height':'100%'},speed,function(){
                    var $theWrapper = $(this);
                    $('#panel').css('height','0px');
                    $theWrapper.css('z-index','0');
                    /* 
                    remove the large image element
                    and the navigation buttons
                     */
                    $this.remove();
                    $('#prev').hide();
                    $('#next').hide();
                });
            });

            /*
            when we are viewing a large image,
            if we navigate to the right/left we need to know
            which image is the corresponding neighbour.
            we know the index of the current picture (current),
            so we can easily get to the neighbour:
             */
            $('#next').bind('click',function(){
                var $this           = $(this);
                var $nextimage      = $('#content img:nth-child('+parseInt(current+2)+')');
                navigate($nextimage,'right');
            });
            $('#prev').bind('click',function(){
                var $this           = $(this);
                var $previmage      = $('#content img:nth-child('+parseInt(current)+')');
                navigate($previmage,'left');
            });

            /*
            given the next or previous image to show,
            and the direction, it loads a new image in the panel.
             */
            function navigate($nextimage,dir){
                /*
                if we are at the end/beginning
                then there's no next/previous
                 */
                if(dir=='left' && current==0)
                    return;
                if(dir=='right' && current==parseInt(totalpictures-1))
                    return;
                $('#loading').show();
                $('<img/>').load(function(){
                    var $theImage = $(this);
                    $('#loading').hide();
                    $('#description').empty().fadeOut();

                    $('#wrapper img').stop().fadeOut(500,function(){
                        var $this = $(this);

                        $this.remove();
                        resize($theImage);

                        $('#wrapper').append($theImage.show());
                        $theImage.stop().fadeIn(800);

                        var title = $nextimage.attr('title');
                        if(title != ''){
                            $('#description').html(title).show();
                        }
                        else
                            $('#description').empty().hide();

                        if(current==0)
                            $('#prev').hide();
                        else
                            $('#prev').show();
                        if(current==parseInt(totalpictures-1))
                            $('#next').hide();
                        else
                            $('#next').show();
                    });
                    /*
                    increase or decrease the current variable
                     */
                    if(dir=='right')
                        ++current;
                    else if(dir=='left')
                        --current;
                }).attr('src', $nextimage.attr('alt'));
            }

            /*
            resizes an image given the window size,
            considering the margin values
             */
            function resize($image){
                var windowH      = $(window).height()-100;
                var windowW      = $(window).width()-80;
                var theImage     = new Image();
                theImage.src     = $image.attr("src");
                var imgwidth     = theImage.width;
                var imgheight    = theImage.height;

                if((imgwidth > windowW)||(imgheight > windowH)){
                    if(imgwidth > imgheight){
                        var newwidth = windowW;
                        var ratio = imgwidth / windowW;
                        var newheight = imgheight / ratio;
                        theImage.height = newheight;
                        theImage.width= newwidth;
                        if(newheight>windowH){
                            var newnewheight = windowH;
                            var newratio = newheight/windowH;
                            var newnewwidth =newwidth/newratio;
                            theImage.width = newnewwidth;
                            theImage.height= newnewheight;
                        }
                    }
                    else{
                        var newheight = windowH;
                        var ratio = imgheight / windowH;
                        var newwidth = imgwidth / ratio;
                        theImage.height = newheight;
                        theImage.width= newwidth;
                        if(newwidth>windowW){
                            var newnewwidth = windowW;
                            var newratio = newwidth/windowW;
                            var newnewheight =newheight/newratio;
                            theImage.height = newnewheight;
                            theImage.width= newnewwidth;
                        }
                    }
                }
                $image.css({'width':theImage.width+'px','height':theImage.height+'px'});
            }
        });
    </script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

404 means the image was not found and indeed it is nowhere to be found...

they're not at the root nor inside lookbook/ folder, so where are they ? put the correct address & it will will work

Comment: Thanks for the response Mikakun, They are in lookbook/images folder which I have them pointing to. The thumbnail images are in lookbook/thumbs and all of them are showing up. for some reason, when the javascript goes to call the full size image, it's not recognizing it as a jpeg but as text/html. any other suggestions?

Comment: no they are not i checked; show us a working link to your images

Comment: so what would the correct address be than? I feel like I tried everything. If I move them directly into the lookbook folder, would the correct link be /lookbook/1.jpg?

Comment: the correct is the one that doesn't show a 404 ! there is no image : http://secondstoryinteriors.com/lookbook/images/14.jpg

Comment: ok, So I found out what it was. For some reason the full-size images got saved as .jpeg and I had them in the code as .jpg. I can't believe it took me this long to see that. Thanks for your help, you made me dig through my code more than I would've!